# I am getting unsupported operand type(s) errors when running my backtesting model in python 3.5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, type-conversion

I want to simulate what would happen to my stock account for various gains and losses that occur in the market.

I am getting an error that that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing12333.py", line 22, in <module>
    account = account + balance
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I tried changing my account = 5000 to account = 5000.01 to try to get the float data type but got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing12333.py", line 21, in <module>
    balance = account * i
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

this is the code I am running

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# In the list  gains_losses I have four different percentages 
# 1%, -22%, 10%, and -5%.
gains_losses = ['.01','-.22','.10','-.05']

# data is a pandas DataFrame that contains a dictionary  
# with a column named "pChg" and the values in that column are 
# the list gains_losses. 
data  = pd.DataFrame({'pChg': gains_losses})

# this is my account balance before I run the test
account = 5000.01   

# This is where I hope to have my account balance updated
# based upon the gains_losses                   
for i in data.pChg:
    balance = account * i
    account = account + balance


# want a final balance printed showing what I won or lost
print(account)
```

The change I made to make it work i is now a float

```
# this is the working code made i a float                   
for i in data.pChg:
    balance = account * float(i)
    account = account + balance
```

Comment: let's be logical: `account` is a float. So `i` is a sequence.

Comment: my logic tells me the above code should work, so to be honest i being a sequence and account be float still in my mind says it should work. This is the long way of saying that I don't understand.

Comment: I don't know pandas, but I would `print(type(i))` just at the start of the loop.

Comment: What are you expecting to be in `data.pChg`?  What do you expect `i` to be as it loops through each element of `data.pChg`?

Comment: I checked i it was a string which now seems obvious because they are in a list with quotes. I changed it to the float data type it works now thank you